# If $f(\mathbb{C})\subset \mathbb{C}-[0,1]$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that $f(z)\neq w$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and for all $w\in [0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$, how to prove that $f$ is constant (without using Picard's little theorem).

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? As a weak hint, whenever a problem begins "Let $f$ be an entire function..." and ends with "...prove $f$ is constant", a particular theorem is begging to be used (or at least thought of).

Comment: Hint: Think about the codomain of the entire function $\frac{1}{f(z)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(\Bbb C)\subset \Bbb C\setminus [0,1]$, take $g=1-\dfrac{1}{f}$, $g$ is an entire function and $g(\Bbb C)\subset \Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R_-$, now we can composite with $\log$, and we obtain an entire function $h=\log \circ g$.

$h$ is an  entire function and $h(\Bbb C)\subset \Bbb R\times ]-\pi, \pi [$.

To finish remark that the function $z\mapsto \dfrac{1}{h(z)-3\pi i}$ is an entire function and it is bounded, by the Liouville's theorem it is constant, hence $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 3):

First show that there is an (injective) holomorphic mapping from
$\Bbb C \setminus [0, 1]$ into the unit disk:

- Start with $z \to 1 - \frac 1z$, this maps $\Bbb C \setminus [0, 1]$
  into $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$.
- Continue with the principal branch of the square root which maps
  $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ to the right half-plane.
- Finally, $z \to \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ maps the right half-plane to the
  unit disk.

Denoting the composition of these mappings with $\phi$ , $\varphi \circ f$ is a bounded holomorphic function.

Liouville's theorem implies thtat $\varphi \circ f$ is constant.
Now conclude that $f$ is constant as well.